# How to find the determinant of this ${P_n^r}\times{P_n^r}$-matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices, roots-of-unity

> Let $1\le r<n$, and let $J$ denote the set of $r$-tuples $\mathbf{j}=(j_1,\ldots,j_r)$ with $1\le j_1,\ldots,j_r\le n$ and $j_s\ne j_t$ for all $s\ne t$. Consider the $P_n^r\times P_n^r$ matrix $A$ (the rows and columns being indexed by $J$) whose $(\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k})$-entry is $\zeta_n^{\mathbf{j}\cdot\mathbf{k}}$, where $\zeta_n=\exp(2\pi i/n)$, and $$\mathbf{j}\cdot\mathbf{k}=j_1k_1+\cdots+j_rk_r.$$

I want to know whether there is a beautiful formula for $\det(A)$, or at least whether $A$ is invertible. If $A$ is invertible, is there an explicit formula for its inverse?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused why you only have $\binom{n}{r}\times\binom{n}{r}$ entries in the matrix.  Is there an assumption that $j_1<j_2<\ldots<j_r$?

Comment: I mean, when $n=3$ and $r=2$, I already see that there are $6$ possible tuples: $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, $(2,1)$, $(2,3)$, $(3,1)$, and $(3,2)$.  So the matrix should be $6\times 6$, not $3\times 3$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have corrected.

Comment: If we allow for repeating entries, then the resulting matrix (relative to the correct choice of basis) is given by $F^{\otimes n} = F \otimes \cdots \otimes F$, where $\otimes$ denotes a Kronecker product and $F = \sqrt{n}W$, where $W$ is a size $n$ [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix).